# Calling .net functions in javascript automation

Tags: playwright, playwright-dotnet

I am barely starting to work with the Playwright and almost don’t have a programming background, therefore my question may sound stupid. I am a test lead and we want to start our automation journey with testers, that have some  javascript experience. However, to speed things up, I want to get some help from our dev team. The dev team prefers working with .net. Expectation is that the dev team prepares a library of functions for varous checks that would be used by the test team. My question is: if the dev team builds such libraries in .net, could we write an automation in javascript and call .net functions? Or everything must be written in either .net or javascript?

If I understood correctly, in .net you can callout javascript function, but not sure about vice versa.

Comment: What kind of functionality is the dev team building?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. JS code is imperative and executes in the browser; that's why you can run it from Playwright